Can't run VS Code installed natively via a .deb package - Permission denied
I'm a newbie dual-booting Ubuntu Linux 24.04 along with Windows 10, and I'm trying to install VS Code natively through the advanced package tool. However, when I try to launch, it I get "Permission denied"
[9303:0629/145947.377873:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
Running with sudo doesn't work. The only way I can make VS Code to run is with the --no-sandbox flag, but I've heard this is very unsafe and shouldn't be done. Flatpak/Snap versions works fine, but some fancy extensions I like don't work in these, and there are also some issues with C#.
Logs from journalctl -xe after launching VS Code:
Jun 29 15:06:58 SJWInc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1719662818.402:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="userns_create" class="namespace" info="Userns create restricted - failed to find unprivileged_userns profile" error=-13 profile="unconfined" pid=9750 comm="code" requested="userns_create" denied="userns_create" target="unprivileged_userns"

Jun 29 15:06:58 SJWInc kernel: traps: code[9750] trap int3 ip:603a037fcb6a sp:7ffe51c28c40 error:0 in code[603a0006c000+7ba9000]

Permissions of /usr/bin/code:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun 29 14:50 /usr/bin/code -> /usr/share/code/bin/code
Things I tried:

Deleting ~/.vscode and ~/.config/Code and providing the permissions to these directories.

Reinstalling VS Code completely with sudo apt purge.

Setting a following AppArmor profile and reloading AppArmor:
include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/code { 
   #include <abstractions/base> 
   #include <abstractions/nameservice> 
   #include <abstractions/user-tmp> 
   #include <abstractions/X>

  /usr/bin/code rix,
  /usr/share/code/** rix,

  network inet stream,

  capability sys_admin,
  capability sys_chroot,
  capability setuid,
  capability setgid,

  userns,

}


Disabling the apparmor profile for VS Code

Setting kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone to 1 with sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1

Rebooting


Any help on resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated!

How did you install it? Like, what apt command did you use?

If it helps, /usr/bin/code is a symlink, so its permissions are set in stone as full access. But just knowing that it's a symlink is important.

I downloaded the .deb package from the official website and ran sudo apt install ./code.deb
also thank you for telling about the symlink!

Found out what caused my problem. I had to set kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone to 0 actually.
If anyone's having the same problem, try running sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0 and adding the kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0 line to the end of /etc/sysctl.conf
